# Синтаксис дорога

Tags: видовые-пары

я посмотрел на клен и увидел как осторожно и медленно отделился от ветки красный лист и косо начал падать к моим ногам это сложное или простое предложение

Answer (score 3):

Это предложение сложное, союзное,  сложноподчиненное. В нем две части: до слова *как* главная часть, со слова как начинается придаточное.